# Appending python Path object with a variable without a forward slash?

Tags: python-3.x, path, pathlib

My code is as follows:

```
>>> file = 'somefile.xyz'
>>> p = Path('/Some/folder/prefix_')
```

If I use the `/` operator for Path, I get:

```
>>> print(p / file)
```

I get:

```
/Some/folder/prefix_/somefile.xyz
```

But I need:

```
/Some/folder/prefix_somefile.xyz
```

How can I do this with `pathlib`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the only way to solve this is to cast to a string and back to a Path object:

```
Path(str(p) + file)
```

Or if you don't wish to import Path locally:

```
p.with_stem(p.stem + file)
```